# How does this for-loop work?

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
for (i=0;i<10,i++;) { cout<<i<<endl;}
```

This will compile and i will end up at 1.

Can someone tell me how this works and why this code will stop at i=1 instead of 10?

Comment: change i<10,i++; to i<10;i++

Comment: I hate it when google goes down. Have you tried bing to look up what the comma operator does?

Comment: Or using the debugger to step through the code to see what's happening?

Comment: The debugger will not help coz i will increase to 1 after the 1st iteration and will not pass the second one. I can not figure out why it will not pass the second one?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer here is that you have an error in your code. That said, let me explain what is going on here.

In C++ the for statement is comprised of three different expressions separated by semi-colons.

```
for (expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3)
```

expr1 is executed before the loop starts. It is generally comprised of either variable declarations or initializations. In your loop that is "i = 0"

expr2 is the conditional expression. This expression is executed to determine if the loop body should run. If this expression evaluates to true, the loop's body executes. This is checked every time the loop executes. In your loop this is "i<10,i++", which is where your bug is. I'm going to come back to this in a second to explain why it is doing what it is doing.

expr3 is generally used for increments. It is executed after the loop body, right before expr2 is re-executed.

So... back to expr2.

In C++ the comma operator executes the expression on the left, but returns the value on the right. In this case that basically means the value of your condition is "i++", which is the value of i BEFORE it is incremented ("++i" would be the value after). That means your condition is "0", but the value of i after the loop is "1".

Comment: This is perfectly clear! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -3):

By simulation, for loop format should be for (i =0; i<10;i++) if you want to get the output 10. This output wold be
1
2
.
.
.
10

Thus, your syntax works as for i=0 add 1 where i <10
thus output 1. There is no increment value aside from it add 1 value from the beginning of the loop.